# Sort Records and Assign Sorting Number - Joint Salutation

Tags: visual-workflow, order, sort, letterhead

I have the following use case:

We would like to create a joint letter salutation for the contacts which are related to an account. For example Dear Mr. Smith, Dear Mrs Smith. Because we want to create joint letters for couples.

This Should be also by Default sorted that the woman is named first like:

Dear Mrs Smith, Dear Mr Smith

To create this I thought about a flow which checks if it is a woman or man and then sort accordingly and writes the sort number into the contacts.
So Mrs Smith would have the Number 1 and Mr Smith the number 2 and in case there is a son it would have the Number 3.
So each record would have an salutation number. In this way we could change the order  manually afterwards in case its needed.

I would like to first sort it with a collectionsort element and then writes the loop number or sortnumber into each contact. And here I am stucked because I dont know how i could assign the sortnumber individually to each element in the loop.

Does anyone has experience with joint letter salutations?

I would be very happy to receive help and many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the Flow by having two Loops; one that loops through the Contact Collection and uses a Formula Variable to assign the correct Sort Value to the Sort Number field using a Case Statement to look at all the controlling fields (Gender, Familial Role, etc) and calculates the number based off that.  Then you can have a Collection Sort element as you stated Sort the Collection by the newly assigned field before going into the Loop that assigns the "Joint Letter Salutation" field.

I would recommend the following however which will lower the complexity of the Flow; Don't assign the Sort value within the Flow but create a Formula field on the Contact record that calculates that itself as based off your description the Sort Value is only determined by values on the Contact itself.  This way you can sort the collection within the initial Get Records element, then go straight into the loop that assigns the Joint Letter Salutation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Input! I am still a little bit stucked. So you mean that it should be a formula that if it is a woman than write number one. If it is a man then number two. Is this what you propose? And regarding the two loop solution: How can I create a formula variable to assign the correct sort value? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Correct. Using pseudocode, the Formula Field on Contact would be something along the lines of: IF Female AND Parent then 1, IF Male AND Parent then 2, IF Male and Child then 3 etc. using whichever criteria you use.  The loop in the Flow would then loop through each Contact for the current Account in order of the Formula Field on the Contact, using an Assign element to add their Salutation to a Text variable  (1st loop would add Mrs. Mom, send loop would add Mr. Dad, third Mr. Son, etc). This Text variable would already have "Dear" added before the loop. Post loop you would then update the Acc.